# Reaching to the effective performance level of the query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this below oracle query Please advise me how can I make it more efficient so that it performance will improve , let me know please if i i have miss anything in it as I am a new one ,any early help would be much appreciated

below is the Plan for the query , Please advise how can i improve it

```
Plan hash value: 44516869

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |                   |  1099 | 39564 |  3770   (1)| 00:00:46 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN                    |                   |  1099 | 39564 |  3770   (1)| 00:00:46 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                |                   |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS               |                   |  1095 | 32850 |  3345   (1)| 00:00:41 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL         | BUSINESS_CONTACTS |  1666 | 14994 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PERSON_PK         |     1 |       |
```

Comment: Your outer `Person P` and inner `Person PR` references are pointing to the same row, which probably isn't what you want.  You should be able to remove one or both of the inner references (and convert the subquery to a regular `JOIN`, anyways).  Side note: please don't use the comma-separated `FROM` clause - always explicitly list out `JOIN`s, and put (almost) all criteria into the `ON` clause.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse i agree

Comment: Does your business_contacts table have an index on person_id? If I read this right, you're doing 1095 full table scans of business_contacts.

Comment: What query? Looks like you removed it and part of the execution plan in an edit, which makes the question a bit meaningless. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can rewrite the query using proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax and no subqueries.  I believe the query is:

```
select p.business_name as Aggregator_Name, 
       pc.business_name as Child_Business_Name, 
       bc.IDV_STATUS 
from business_contacts bc join
     person p
     on bc.person_id = p.person_id join
     person pc
     on pc.parent_person_id = p.person_id;
```

Then for this query you want indexes on `person(person_id, business_name)` and `person(parent_person_id, business_name)`.